# JQuery UI Slider shows up on one page but not on other although almost similar code

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

Ok this is really driving me crazy. Here is a working example of what i am trying to achieve:
http://www.rockaholics-cologne.de/root/testslidenew.php

However in my other php script where i have exactly the same css and js libraries included and basically the same code for the funtcion of the slider except that the values are different the slider doesnt display:

```
<tbody>
<?php
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $sql = "SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(starttime), TIME_TO_SEC(endtime), date FROM wishtimes WHERE date BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate' ORDER BY date";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);      
    $wishtimes = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $weekday = date('l', strtotime($row['date']));
        $wishtimes[$weekday] = $row;
    }
    $dates = date_range($startDate, $endDate);
    print_r ($wishtimes);
    print_r($dates);
    $weekdays = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
    for($i=0; $i < count($weekdays); $i++) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $weekdays[$i]?></td>
<?php
    if (isset($wishtimes[$weekdays[$i]])) { 
?>
    <td colspan="25">TEST<div id="slider<?php echo $i?>"></div></td>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var start = "<?php echo $wishtimes[$weekdays[$i]]['TIME_TO_SEC(starttime)']?>";
        var end = "<?php echo $wishtimes[$weekdays[$i]]['TIME_TO_SEC(endtime)']?>";
        start = start / 60;
        end = end / 60;
        $("#slider<?php echo $i?>").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 1440, /* Hour * 60 from 0:00 to 24:00 */
            step: 15,
            values: [ start, end ],
            slide: function(e, ui) {
                var hours = Math.floor(ui.value / 60);
                var minutes = ui.value - (hours * 60);

                if(hours.length == 1) hours = '0' + hours;
                if(minutes.length == 1) minutes = '0' + minutes;

                $('#something').html(hours+':'+minutes);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>           
    <td>
        <a href><i class="icon-minus-sign"></i></a>
    </td>
<?php
    } else {
?>
    <td colspan="25">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle(id) {
            if ($('#'+id).is(":hidden")) {
                $('#'+id).slideDown("fast");
            } else {
                $('#'+id).slideUp("fast");
            }
        }
        </script>
        <button id="addwishtime" onclick="toggle('<?php echo $i?>')">Add</button></br>      
        <div id="<?php echo $i?>" style="display: none;">
        <?php
            /*          --- select FIRM of the current user ---
            $sql = "SELECT firm FROM team WHERE username='$log_username' LIMIT 1";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                $firmname = $row[0];
            } */    
            $sql = "SELECT starttime, endtime, shiftname, firm FROM shifts WHERE firm='TestBusiness' ORDER BY starttime ASC";
            $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
            while($shifts = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        ?>
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $dates[$i]?>" name="date">
            <?php echo $dates[$i]?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shifts['firm']?>" name="firm">
            <?php echo $shifts['firm']?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shifts['starttime']?>" name="starttime">
            <?php echo $shifts['starttime']?>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $shifts['endtime']?>" name="endtime">
            <input type="submit" value="<b><?php echo $shifts['shiftname']?></b> Start: <?php echo $shifts['start']?>  End: <?php echo $shifts['end']?>">
        </form>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
    }
?>
</tbody>
```

The "TEST" gets printed out but no slider. If i look into F12 on Chrome i can see that values are set for start and end. The slider div also gets created but is simply at a height of 0px

What am i missing here??

EDIT

I just removed this script from datepicker which is also on the same page and as soon as i do it shows the slider but how can i get both to work???

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var startDay;
    var endDay;

    var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
        }, 1);
    }

    $('.week-picker').datepicker( {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        firstDay: 1,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
            var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            startDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() +1);
            endDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 7);
            var startDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' +  (date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() +1)) + "-" + ((date.getDate() - date.getDay() +1) < 10 ? '0' +  (date.getDate() - date.getDay() +1) : (date.getDate() - date.getDay() +1));
            var endDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' +  (date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1)) + "-" + ((date.getDate() - date.getDay() +7) < 10 ? '0' +  (date.getDate() - date.getDay() +7) : (date.getDate() - date.getDay() +7));
            window.location.href = "?startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate;
            selectCurrentWeek();            
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var cssClass = '';
            if(date >= startDay && date <= endDay)
                cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
            return [true, cssClass];
        },
        onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
            selectCurrentWeek();
        }
    });

    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you have one more phrase at the end "}" remove and check

Comment: Thanks but that was my mistake it was from a while loop from before the posted code :/

Comment: Ok i just figured something out by accident. I have another function() for JQuery datepicker and if i remove it it shows the slider. So how do these two interact?

Answer (score 0):

I hope the problem should be , you are setting the range values as string but number or integer type required.please convert the string to number by using the following method or use your own method to convert.

> start = parseInt(start);  end = parseInt(end);

try this, i hope you will get answer. thank you.

Comment: I thought the MYSQL TIME_TO_SEC function allready turns times into numeric values?

Comment: actually you are assigning values inside a quotation , so javascript will consider as a string.

Comment: I added the parseInt but no changes :(

Also showed another working example in my original questions where i also dont use the parseInt and its working nonetheless

Comment: try to create a slider outside the table data (<td>) element , i.e in a div element,set its width and height to 100%.

Comment: Hey thank you but check my comment on my questions. Seems like datepicker and slider are interacting!?!? Cause if i remove the function of datepicker it shows the slider. But both functions dont work